# How to hide gutter output in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: text-editor, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 in conjunction with the JSLint package and the SublimeLinter package. The linter gets run every time I hit save, and when I hit 'ctrl-L.' However, the "gutter" window that pops up and lists lint errors does not provide an option to hide itself. I cannot find anything in the options. Is there a hotkey or menu option that I am missing? I have very limited screen space and as useful as a linter is, I don't want a chunk of my screen taken up by it at all times.

Comment: You're running [JSLint](https://github.com/darrenderidder/Sublime-JSLint) _and_ [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3)? Or SublimeLinter with the [JSLint Plugin](https://github.com/devdoc/SublimeLinter-jslint)? Assuming the latter, did you look into [this setting](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/global_settings.html#show-errors-on-save)? The former would be redundant.